# IndexOutOfRangeException error when DataGridView header is clicked

Tags: vb.net

Iam trying to get DataGridView rowIndex and set it to textbox and all is well with this code

```
Private Sub dgv_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv.CellContentClick
    isitxt(e.RowIndex)
    btnInsert.Enabled = False
    btnUpdate.Enabled = True
    btnDelete.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

and

```
Sub isitxt(ByVal x As Integer)
    txtIDBarang.Text = dgv.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value
    txtNamaBarang.Text = dgv.Rows(x).Cells(1).Value
    cbJenisBarang.Text = dgv.Rows(x).Cells(2).Value
    numHargaBeli.Value = dgv.Rows(x).Cells(3).Value
    numHargaJual.Value = dgv.Rows(x).Cells(4).Value
End Sub
```

But i got `IndexOutOfRangeException` when i clicked on Column Header. how can i handle it ?

Comment: Use a `try/catch/finally` block or test `x` to see if it's a valid row index

Comment: `if (e.RowIndex > -1) {...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, that if you use CellContentClick, the code will be executed only if the user actually aims at text content of a cell. Usually a CellClick is makes more sense.

As for your code, you can debug and see, what's in "x", when you get an error - I guess "-1"... You can handle it then. However, the reason for this should not be in your code above.

You can also set `SelectionMode = FullRowSelect` and do it following way:

```
Private Sub dgv_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv.CellClick
  isitxt(Me.dgv.selectedRows(0).index)
  btnInsert.Enabled = False
  btnUpdate.Enabled = True
  btnDelete.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Unless you want to handle the cells separately, users usually prefer the FullRowSelect mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `On error resume next` like this :

```
Private Sub dgv_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv.CellContentClick
  on error resume next
  isitxt(e.RowIndex)
  btnInsert.Enabled = False
  btnUpdate.Enabled = True
  btnDelete.Enabled = True
End Sub
```